# Match 2 string with minors differences

Tags: php, string

I would like to know if anyone know a good algorithm to match 2 string accepting minor differences such as:

First word is the first string to compare with the second string.

```
EX1: hellos - hello

EX2: Hello  - hello

EX3: Helo   - hello

EX4: ello   - hello

EX5: I own iphone - i own a iphone

EX6: I beleive in god - i believe in god
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about your goal? Are you looking for auto-correction?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php ?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins no looks like he is wanting to know how to check for only minor differences such as spelling or caps as compared to entirely different words.

Comment: Perfect jValdron, I never knew this function existed xD

Comment: see similar_text() metaphone() soundex() levenshtein() and if you get it working good go apply to work at google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The match algorithme what you are searching for is fuzzy math or aproximate match

You can try
http://elonen.iki.fi/code/misc-notes/appr-search-php/

I'm not associated with them nor did I test the code, but it might send you on the right track.